# In lottery to get second best list of winning combinations

Tags: python, probability

Total numbers are 1 to 36. These numbers needs to be arranged in 5 positions. If only 4 numbers are correct , then combinations of odds winning is 2432.

Is there any function or logic to get this winning combination. I was able to get all combinations for all 5 winning numbers using below python code.

```
num_list =[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36]

list(it.combinations(num_list, 5))
```

Comment: 1) So you managed to find `itertools-combinations` to get the combinations 5 out of 36, but you have difficulties to find all 4 out of 36 combinations? Really? 2) Why not use `range(1, 37)` as your num_list?

Comment: Please let me re-phrase my question . I am looking for combinations of 4 correct numbers in 5 positions . Code I have written is for 5 correct numbers in 5 positions.